# How to deform contour in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, contour

I am trying to figure out how I can connect the curve along A to K with the top-right-most point. In other words, I want to still have a little more of the circle left on the right piece of the plot; right now I have a straight line along K to H(...) but would much prefer a little-bit more of a curve from K to H(...). How do I do this? Also -- if I wanted another small semi-circle above the point, say x=-1.5, y=.2, and also one below x=-1.5, y=.2, is there any way to do this without ruining this image? Thanks! So far I have something that looks like this (not exactly, but close):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings,positioning}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %configurable parameters
        \def\gap{0.4}
        \def\bigradius{4}
        \def\littleradius{1}
        %axes
        \draw[line width=2pt,->](-1.5*\bigradius,0) -- (1.5*\bigradius,0)
        (0,-1.5*\bigradius) -- (0,1.5*\bigradius);
        \draw[line width=2pt,->] (0,0)--(45:\littleradius);
        \draw[line width=2pt,->](0,0) -- (135:\bigradius); \node[above
        right] at (45:\littleradius/1.5) {\large\bf{$\varepsilon$}};
        \draw[line width=1pt,decoration={markings,
            mark=at position 0.07 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},%{latex}},
            mark=at position 0.17 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},
            mark=at position 0.27 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},
            mark=at position 0.35 with {\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},%{latex}},
            mark=at position 0.47 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},
            mark=at position 0.53 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},%{latex}},
            mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},%{latex}},
            mark=at position 0.65 with {\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},%{latex}},
            mark=at position 0.7 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},
            mark=at position 0.8 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},
            mark=at position 0.85 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},
            mark=at position 0.955 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}}},%{latex}}},
        postaction={decorate}]
        let
        \n1={asin(\gap/2/\bigradius)},
        \n2={asin(\gap/2/\littleradius)}
        in (180-\n1:\bigradius) -- (-180-\n2:\littleradius)
        arc(180-\n2:-180+\n2:\littleradius)--(-180+\n1:\bigradius)
        arc(-180+\n1:-90:\bigradius)--(3,-4)--(3,4)--(0,4)arc(90:(180-\n1):\bigradius);
        \coordinate (T) at (135:2); \node[above] at (T){$T$}; 
        \coordinate (H) at (1.5*\bigradius,0); \node[below] at (H){\Large\bf {x}};
        \coordinate (J) at (0,1.5*\bigradius); \node[left] at (J){$\Large\bf y$}; 
        \coordinate (C) at (\littleradius,0); \node[below right] at (C) {\Large\bf {C}};
        \coordinate (D) at ({180-asin(\gap/2/\littleradius)}:1); \node[above left] at (D) {$ \Large\bf B$}; 
        \coordinate (E) at ({-180+asin(\gap/2/\littleradius)}:1); \node[below left] at (E) {$\Large\bf D$}; 
        \coordinate (F) at ({180-asin(\gap/2/\bigradius)}:\bigradius); \node[above left] at (F) {$\Large\bf A$}; 
        \coordinate (G) at ({-180+asin(\gap/2/\bigradius)}:\bigradius); \node[below left] at (G) {$\Large\bf  E$}; 
        \coordinate (P) at (0,-4); \node[below right] at (P) {$\Large\bf F$}; \coordinate(Q) at (3,-4); \node[right] at (Q) {$\Large\bf G(\gamma-iT)$}; 
        \coordinate (R) at (3,4); \node[right] at (R) {$\Large\bf H(\gamma+iT)$}; 
        \coordinate (S) at (0,4);\node[above right] at (S) {$\Large\bf K$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

and this is what I am looking for:
[image]

Comment: I didn't understand your problem.

Comment: From the point F to the point G(gamma-iT), I was looking to continue the circle. Same goes for the point K to the point H(gamma+iT).

Comment: @AndréC there would be no right angles and it would no longer be a semi-circle, but a semi-circle +sum extra arc-length.

Comment: Add a freehand drawing of the desired result.

Comment: @AndréC Alright I just did, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simply changed the path so that it goes through the points `(45:\bigradius)`

```
let
        \n1={asin(\gap/2/\bigradius)},
        \n2={asin(\gap/2/\littleradius)}
        in (180-\n1:\bigradius) -- (-180-\n2:\littleradius)
        arc(180-\n2:-180+\n2:\littleradius)--(-180+\n1:\bigradius)
        arc(-180+\n1:-45:\bigradius)--(45:\bigradius)arc(45:(180-\n1):\bigradius);
```

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings,positioning}
\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        %configurable parameters
        \def\gap{0.4}
        \def\bigradius{4}
        \def\littleradius{1}
        %axes
        \draw[line width=2pt,->](-1.5*\bigradius,0) -- (1.5*\bigradius,0)
        (0,-1.5*\bigradius) -- (0,1.5*\bigradius);
        \draw[line width=2pt,->] (0,0)--(45:\littleradius);
        \draw[line width=2pt,->](0,0) -- (135:\bigradius); \node[above
        right] at (45:\littleradius/1.5) {\large\bf{$\varepsilon$}};
        \draw[line width=1pt,decoration={markings,
            mark=at position 0.07 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},%{latex}},
            mark=at position 0.17 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},
            mark=at position 0.27 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},
            mark=at position 0.35 with {\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},%{latex}},
            mark=at position 0.47 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},
            mark=at position 0.53 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},%{latex}},
            mark=at position 0.6 with {\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},%{latex}},
            mark=at position 0.65 with {\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},%{latex}},
            mark=at position 0.7 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},
            mark=at position 0.8 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},
            mark=at position 0.85 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}},
            mark=at position 0.955 with{\arrow[line width =2pt]{>}}},%{latex}}},
        postaction={decorate}]
        let
        \n1={asin(\gap/2/\bigradius)},
        \n2={asin(\gap/2/\littleradius)}
        in (180-\n1:\bigradius) -- (-180-\n2:\littleradius)
        arc(180-\n2:-180+\n2:\littleradius)--(-180+\n1:\bigradius)
        arc(-180+\n1:-45:\bigradius)--(45:\bigradius)arc(45:(180-\n1):\bigradius);
        \coordinate (T) at (135:2);
         \node[above] at (T){$T$}; 
        \coordinate (H) at (1.5*\bigradius,0);
         \node[below] at (H){\Large\bf {x}};
        \coordinate (J) at (0,1.5*\bigradius);
         \node[left] at (J){$\Large\bf y$}; 
        \coordinate (C) at (\littleradius,0);
         \node[below right] at (C) {\Large\bf {C}};
        \coordinate (D) at ({180-asin(\gap/2/\littleradius)}:1);            \node[above left] at (D) {$ \Large\bf B$}; 
        \coordinate (E) at ({-180+asin(\gap/2/\littleradius)}:1);           \node[below left] at (E) {$\Large\bf D$}; 
        \coordinate (F) at ({180-asin(\gap/2/\bigradius)}:\bigradius); 
        \node[above left] at (F) {$\Large\bf A$}; 
        \coordinate (G) at ({-180+asin(\gap/2/\bigradius)}:\bigradius); 
        \node[below left] at (G) {$\Large\bf  E$}; 
        \coordinate (P) at (0,-4);
        
         \node[below right] at (P) {$\Large\bf F$};
         \coordinate(Q) at (3,-4);
        \node[right] at (Q) {$\Large\bf G(\gamma-iT)$}; 
        \coordinate (R) at (3,4); 
        \node[right] at (R) {$\Large\bf H(\gamma+iT)$}; 
        \coordinate (S) at (0,4);
        \node[above right] at (S) {$\Large\bf K$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 very fast......

Comment: You just have to move the nodes.
Note that your code can be simplified. It is useless to do coordinate then node. Both can be done simultaneously.

Comment: Ah alright. Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there anyway to get the smaller semi-circles along the negative axis?

Comment: I have to leave and I won't be online until tomorrow. We'll see tomorrow, if not, ask a new question.

Comment: What do you mean by `get the smaller semi-circles along the negative axis`? I don't understand.